# Golang parsing timestamp format

Tags: json, go, datetime-format, telegraf

I have a telegraph service that parses a timestamp in json.

I get this timestamp for example in json messages:

```
2017-09-04T04:00:00
```

But in the telegraph settings I can't set the parsing correctly, which I understand is in the go language.

```
time_format: "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: format "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" resulted in error: parsing time "2017-09-04T04:00:00" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "Z07:00"
```

And somehow I can't set this to work.

Comment: Remove the `Z` (and anything that follows it) from `time_format`. https://go.dev/play/p/X-oG87Npho1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time layout includes a timezone component but your time doesn't.  Try this layout:

`"2006-01-02T15:04:05"`